# Spring Boot Actuator - env endpoint provides response with active_profiles and property_sources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-actuator

Once I invoke spring actuator endpoint (http://localhost:8080/actuator/env) it provides response in following format which include _ in between,

```
{
active_profiles: [ ],
property_sources: [
 .....
```

This includes underscore in between, and this is different comparing to our other services. My expected response is without '_' as follows:

```
activeProfiles: [ ],
propertySources: [
```

I am not sure why it generates response with '_' can someone please help on this,
Thanks

Comment: So there should be some difference between the two projects, e.g. springboot version, yml vs properties file... Did you try to find the difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.